# Can I loop an Azure Pipelines task on a runtime array variable instead of an array parameter?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In Azure Pipelines, I understand that you can define tasks which are iterated based on an array of values provided as a parameter, like follows:

template.yml

```
parameters:
  param: []
 
jobs:
- ${{each p in parameters.param}}:
  - script: 'echo ${{ p }}'
```

pipeline.yml:

```
steps: 
- template: template.yml
  parameters: 
    param: ["a", "b"]
```

However, in this case, you have to know your desired values for `param` at the pipeline's compile time. In my use case, I want to run [the `Cache@2` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) to create unique cache items for an unknown number of files produced by my build with potentially unknown names.

I know that I can use a bash task to find and list these files, similar to this:

```
steps:
- bash |
    FILE_LIST=''
    while IFS= read -r; do
      FILE_LIST+=" $REPLY "
    done < <(find ../../build -name '*.desired_extension' -type d | xargs basename)
```

And then, presumably, I could expose this to other tasks as a variable by doing something along the lines of this (not sure if the array syntax is right, but the intention should be clear):

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fileList]\"[$FILE_LIST]\""
```

But my plan breaks down here: since the task looping is driven by parameters rather than variables, I don't think I can trigger a dynamic number of `Cache@2` tasks based on this runtime-computed variable. Is there some other way I can achieve this goal of creating multiple cache instances where the count isn't known until runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to do this using output variables and matrix configuration. First you need to create output variables with json content and then pass it to matrix configuration. Please tak a look on this example:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: JobA
  steps:
  - pwsh: |
      $json="{'job1': {'Work': 'work1'}, 'job2': {'Work': 'work2'}}"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=targets;isOutput=true]$json"
    name: setTargets
  - script: echo $(setTargets.targets)
    name: echovar

- job: buildSrc
  dependsOn: JobA
  displayName: Build source
  strategy:
    matrix: $[ dependencies.JobA.outputs['setTargets.targets'] ]
  variables:
    targets: $[ dependencies.JobA.outputs['setTargets.targets'] ]
  steps:
  - pwsh: Write-Host "${{ convertToJson(variables) }}"
    displayName: 'Print all variables via expression'
```

And voila we have dunamiclly created jobs. Now you need to put cache task inside this job, get values provided via matrix confoguration and you should have this solved.

[image]